# i want to access all keys and values of this json objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>employees var having the json array n objects</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var employees = [{
    "_id": "P_00001",
    "Product": "SEA EXPORT",
    "Status": "Active",
    "Origin": "JEBEL ALI(DUBAI), United Arab Emirates (AEJEA)",
    "Destination": "CHENNAI, India (INMAA)",
    "CreatedDate": "2016-01-13T07:17:05.251Z"
}];

for( i=0 ; i < employees.length ; i++ )
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +="<br/>" + employees[i]["_id"] + " " + employees[i][key()];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- json object with keys and values ihave stored in var employees
- i dont know how to display the keys and values of the object using forloop

Comment: Where's the "JSON object", all I see is a regular array ?

Comment: [*There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"*](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: im not good with json. tell me how to create it and access the keys n values. especially the keys.

Comment: And the answer is `Object.keys(employees[0]).forEach(function(key) {...`

Comment: can u be lil more specific? i mean the exact code for that ?

Comment: That is the exact code? -> **https://jsfiddle.net/pz8frb6r/**

Comment: Thanks A Lot... This Help me a lot.. the thing is im new with js and json.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for/in` loop to access all keys in an object, and then use that key to access the value:

```
var txt = "";
var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25}; 
var x;
for (x in person) {
    txt += person[x] + " ";
}
alert(txt);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_for_in

**EDIT 1**

This function highlights the key and value:

```
var employees = [{
    "_id": "P_00001",
    "Product": "SEA EXPORT",
    "Status": "Active",
    "Origin": "JEBEL ALI(DUBAI), United Arab Emirates (AEJEA)",
    "Destination": "CHENNAI, India (INMAA)",
    "CreatedDate": "2016-01-13T07:17:05.251Z"
}];

for( var e of employees ) {  
  for( var key in e ) {
      alert('The key "'+ key + '" represents the value "' + e[key] + '"')
  }
}
```

Comment: This one is for accessing the values. not for keys.

Comment: When this loop is running, the `x` variable contains the key and `person[x]` represents the value in the object at the keys position. Therefore this method accesses both the key and value.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` loops on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can  :

```
for(i in employees){
    var key = i;
    var val = employees[i];
    for(j in val){
        var sub_key = j;
        var sub_val = val[j];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +="<br/>" + (sub_key) + " " + sub_val;
    }

}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm6p7o1b/)